# How to save my customed AMI to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have Quick Launch an Ubuntu Instance and install some software in it. Then I created a AMI from it. How can I save this my own AMI to a S3 bucket for reusing?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260925/how-do-i-save-an-ami-to-a-s3-bucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create an AMI from it, it is stored in s3. However, you are not able to access or download this AMI.

You can only export images that you had originally imported.

Comment: But I want to save it to my own S3 bucket.

Comment: As a said before, this is not allowed within EC2 unless you provided the original image via VM import.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a misunderstanding in the original question.  You don't need to "save an AMI to an S3 bucket for re-using".  If you created an AMI, that is all you need to start new instances using that image.

Comment: Frankly its my homework:"Build your own Hadoop AMI, starting from a basic Ubuntu AMI. You have to use Hadoop 1.0.4. You are required to store this AMI in S3, and its name must include your last name."I am confused about"store this AMI in S3"